# unable to push from mac laptop, terminal (Git) to my GITHUB

Tags: git, macos, github

```
$git --version     //checked the version of git
$cd hello-world    //created master branch hello-world
$vi readme.txt    //created branch in master branch
$git add readme.txt   //adding the branch to the staging area
$git commit -m "my first git commit"  //commiting the file readme.txt 
$git push origin master      //pushing the branch to GITHUB
fatal error:Failed to connect to 192.168.1.150 port 1080: Operation 
timed out
fatal error: unable to access 'https://github.com/aishwarya/hello-
world.git/': Unsupported proxy '123@github.com:8080', libcurl is built 
without the HTTPS-proxy support.--
```

these are the two errors I am getting and unable to push anything to GITHUB.I am using Macbook pro with Mojave installed.Can someone please 
help in this issue..

```
  --Thanks in advance
```

Comment: "git --version     //checked the version of git"... OK: what version of Git do you have?

Comment: What's `githhub.com` (with double-h)?

Answer (score 1):

First, do you need to use a proxy to access internet?
If not, make sure you don't have any environment variable _proxy:

```
env|grep -i proxy
```

Check also your git config:

```
git config -l --show-origin|grep -i proxy
```

Check also your `~/.curlrc`: if you don't need a proxy, you would have to cleanup that file entries.

Finally, check your `curl --version` (its output should include SSL).
Try and [install `curl --with-openssl`](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/curl).

Comment: Thank you for your time!I checked above all you mentioned and everything is installed properly.

Comment: @aishwaryat What version of Git do you have?